# Windows 8: Wubi uninstaller provided by Ubuntu 10.10 doesn’t work

Tags: windows-8, wubi

A few days ago I migrated from Windows 7 to Windows 8. Some of the settings from the previous OS have been saved. For instance Ubuntu which was installed by Wubi ages ago. It still has its virtual partition and the Windows 8 boot-loader “add-on” (I mean GUI boot-loader). Now, while I’m trying to run wubi_uninstall under Windows 8, nothing happens. Is there any solution for uninstalling my old copy of Ubuntu safely without damaging my newly installed copy of Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Visual BCD Editor](http://visual-bcd-editor.en.softonic.com/) to get rid of the entry. Please note that Wubi installs Ubuntu into a file and thus you can simply remove the files / directories to get rid of the Ubuntu partition file.

The files are located under `C:\ubuntu\disks\` or perhaps `C:\windows.old\ubuntu\disks` if you have upgraded; worst case you can search for `ubuntu`. If you feel like you need to access them you can follow [these links](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_the_Wubi_files_from_Windows.3F).

Comment: And there is no solution to resuscitate ubuntu Wubi for now?

Comment: @Zacateras: If it ended up in `C:\windows.old\ubuntu\disks` then moving it to `C:\ubuntu\disks` might work; another option is to move it out of the way (as a back-up), then install Wubi on Windows 8 and overwrite the file that the Wubi installer made with your existing file. If that also doesn't work you'll have to port the files over...

Comment: Ubuntu files weren't touched after migrating and are still in C:\ubuntu. Replacing wubi for newer version doesn't work for me.